# Using Month function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, sheet1 is the report, and sheet2 is the result. In the result sheet I have in column A the months represented as "Jan", "Feb", etc and so on. In my report sheet I have the months represented in number.

My requirement is , to check the column W of report sheet is same as Column A of the result sheet. If they are same, then I have to print the count result in result sheet.

I have the below code to return the month

```
Sub month()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim totalrows As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Report")
totalrows = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox (totalrows & "   Check")
      For i = 5 To totalrows
       ' get the current week in column 23
         Cells(i, 23).Value = Month(Now)
      Next
End Sub
```

the below code, checks for the current month in both the sheets and prints the count value . could someone help, how I can say the VBA that the Column W containing 9 is same as Column A containing September.  ?  The month entered in the column A is manual entry.

```
Sub result()
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, cntR As Long, CntS As Long, cntT As Long, cntU As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Result")
    Sheets("Report").Select
    For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht.Columns(1))
    ' get the current week from column A of the sheet result
        If sht.Range("A" & i) = Val(Month(Now)) Then Exit For
    Next i

    sht.Range("C" & i & ":" & "J" & i).ClearContents
    For j = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("W"))
    ' if column A and column W are same, then count 1, in column A, R; S, T, U
        If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("W" & j) Then
            If Range("R" & j) = "1" Then cntR = cntR + 1
            If Range("S" & j) = "1" Then CntS = CntS + 1
            If Range("T" & j) = "1" Then cntT = cntT + 1
            If Range("U" & j) = "1" Then cntU = cntU + 1
        End If
    Next j
   ' print the count values in the respective column
    If cntR <> 0 Then sht.Range("C" & i) = cntR
    If CntS <> 0 Then sht.Range("D" & i) = CntS
    If cntT <> 0 Then sht.Range("E" & i) = cntT
    If cntU <> 0 Then sht.Range("F" & i) = cntU
    If cntR + CntS + cntT + cntU <> 0 Then
        sht.Range("G" & i) = cntR / (cntR + CntS + cntT + cntU)
        sht.Range("H" & i) = CntS / (cntR + CntS + cntT + cntU)
        sht.Range("I" & i) = cntT / (cntR + CntS + cntT + cntU)
        sht.Range("J" & i) = cntU / (cntR + CntS + cntT + cntU)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are your values in column A text or are the dates formatted `"mmm"`

Comment: @ScottCraner the are text

Comment: `If Month("1 " & sht.Range("A" & i) & " 2017") = sht.range("W" & j) Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner I am getting application defined error